# Why do some variables require initialization and some don't in the same script?

Tags: perl, scope, global-variables, strict

I am experimenting with Perl, and have written the following quadratic equation solver.

```perl
#! perl
use strict;
use Math::Complex;
use v5.22;

say "Quadratic Equation Solver";

print "Enter a: ";
$a = <STDIN>;

print "Enter b: ";
$b = <STDIN>;

print "Enter c: ";
my $c = <STDIN>;

my $dis = ($b ** 2) - (4 * $a * $c);

say "x1 = ".((0 - $b + sqrt($dis)) / (2 * $a));
say "x2 = ".((0 - $b - sqrt($dis)) / (2 * $a));
```

If I leave out `my` when creating the variables `$c` and `$dis`, I get an error message that reads:

```
Global symbol "$c" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $c"?)
Global symbol "$dis" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $dis"?)
```

However, I do not get any error message for leaving it out by the variables `$a` and `$b`. Why is that? Furthermore, I am getting the error message even if I leave out `use strict`. I thought that Perl allows you to use uninitialized variables if you leave that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's beacuse you happened to pick two variables (`$a` and `$b`) that are always declared as globals in all packages - so they can always be used without declaring them. If you'd chosen `$A` and `$B` instead, you'd get the same error as for `$c` and `$dir` if you leave `my` out.

Further reading about `$a` and `$b` @
[`perlmaven.com`: Don't use `$a` and `$b` outside of sort, not even for examples](https://perlmaven.com/dont-use-a-and-b-variables)

Comment: Thank you, however, why am I getting the warnings even when I leave out `use strict`?

Comment: @ap You're welcome. What warnings? I don't see anything about warnings in your question

Comment: I am getting the same error messages even if I leave out `use strict`, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: @ap It's because you  `use v5.22;` - "_if the specified Perl version is greater than or equal to 5.12.0, strictures are enabled lexically as with `use strict`._"